# There are two kinds of tabs in Apache Superset dashboards. How do I make the kind that applies to the entire dashboard?

Tags: apache-superset

In one Dashboard that I inherited from a colleague, I see the following kind of tabs:
["meta" tabs that float above dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fOGr.png). Note that these are attached to the title element on the page.

On a new dashboard, I can't figure out how to replicate this arrangement. If I go into edit mode and add a "tab" component, it shows up below, "within" the dashboard [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOAA5.png). I want to replicate the first kind. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

there was a bug for a few weeks on `master` that disabled top level dashboard tabs but it's since been fixed.

What version of Superset are you using (if you're using a versioned release)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a difference, simply that the first example has a lot more tabs while the second only has one tab, and the dashboard hasn't been saved with that one tab, so you can't see what is the selected tab yet.